# When Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Tags: matlab

What I am doing wrong here? I am using MatLab.

*Error: Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts.*

```
    con_var = zeros(num_rea,num_var);
    for i = 1:num_var
        for l = 1:num_rea

            str = [var_nam{i},'/', var_nam2{i},'_', num2str(l), '.out'];
            tmp = readGEO( str );
            con_var(l,i,:) = tmp; %'here the error'

        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
con_var = cell(num_var,num_rea);
for i = 1:num_var
    for l = 1:num_rea

        str = [var_nam{i},'/', var_nam2{i},'_', num2str(l), '.out'];
        tmp = readGEO( str );
        con_var{l,i}= tmp;

    end
end
```

will work on any matlab object tmp, but will not be optimal if e.g. tmp is a single number or fixed-size object.

You can retrieve the contents of con_var with e.g.

```
con_var{1,1}
```